# Get the variable in the path of a URI

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

In Spring MVC I have a controller that listens to all requests coming to `/my/app/path/controller/*`.

Let's say a request comes to `/my/app/path/controller/blah/blah/blah/1/2/3`.

How do I get the `/blah/blah/blah/1/2/3` part, i.e. the part that matches the `*` in the handler mapping definition.

In other words, I am looking for something similar that `pathInfo` does for servlets but for controllers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Spring 3 you can use the @ PathVariable annotation to grab parts of the URL.

Here's a quick example from http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getBooking(@PathVariable("hotel") long hotelId, @PathVariable("booking") long bookingId, Model model) {
    Hotel hotel = hotelService.getHotel(hotelId);
    Booking booking = hotel.getBooking(bookingId);
    model.addAttribute("booking", booking);
    return "booking";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring 2.5 you can override any method that takes an instance of HttpServletRequest as an argument.

[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractController.html#handleRequest%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)

In Spring 3 you can add a HttpServletRequest argument to your controller method and spring will automatically bind the request to it.
e.g.

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelMap doSomething( HttpServletRequest request) { ... }
```

In either case, this object is the same request object you work with in a servlet, including the getPathInfo method.